# Cant solve error code 9

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create a log file. When trying to execute this code I get Error 9; subscript out of range.

I'd really appreciate your help, the code seems to run fine for other files (1 for each month of the year) but not for all, and I don't understand.

! [my code] https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiE0k.jpg

This is also my first question asked regarding VBA, so if you need more screenshots or information, be sure to ask.

```
    Sub Information()

    Dim x, y, z, g, h, f, e, d As Integer

'  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Departure

    x = 6
    y = 12
    z = 2
    f = 2
    g = 16
    e = 1

    For i = 1 To 300000000
        If e > 30000000 Then
            f = f + 1
            e = 1
            z = 2
        Else
            If Worksheets("Arrival").Cells(f, 15).Value = Worksheets("Information").Cells(z, x).Value Then
               Worksheets("Arrival").Cells(f, 16).Value = Worksheets("Information").Cells(z, 3).Value
               Worksheets("Arrival").Cells(f, 14).Value = Worksheets("Information").Cells(z, 4).Value
               Worksheets("Arrival").Cells(f, 17).Value = Worksheets("Information").Cells(z, 5).Value
               Worksheets("Arrival").Cells(f, 18).Value = Worksheets("Information").Cells(z, 11).Value
               Worksheets("Arrival").Cells(f, 19).Value = Worksheets("Information").Cells(z, 7).Value

                z = 2
                f = f + 1


            Else

               z = z + 1
               e = e + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

Thanks a LOT in advance,

Jason

Comment: One of the sheet names is incorrect, hence error 9. Once you fix that, you will get error 1004, as 300000000 is way more than number if rows in sheet (Excel 2007+) 1048576. another possibility is your sheets and macro are in separate workbooks. fully qalify sheet names with worbook instance. Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets("Arrival")

Answer (score 0):

Declare all your variables like this:

```
Dim x as long
Dim y as long
dim z as long
etc.
```

and try again. Probably it would work.

And by the way, excel has only 2^20 rows, which is a bit more than 1 million. You are using 30 million on your loops. Try to think of something else.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work (yet). Any other suggestions?  http://imgur.com/a/oUSVO

Comment: Check the edition. You exceed the limits of rows in excel. Go below 2^20 rows and not 30 and 300 millions in your code.

Comment: I've changed it to 1 million and e<100000, but I'm still getting the same error at the same piece of code.    Really appreciating your help

Comment: write `debug.print f,z,x` on the line before the error and check the values.

Comment: Where do I put the debug.print line exactly? I tried to put it before the yellow highlighted string http://imgur.com/a/ojSLU

Comment: Exactly as you showed. Put the cursor before the `If` and press enter.

Comment: Yes, it helps. What are the values of Arrival B16 and Information B3?

Comment: And add **all** the variables to the debug.print like this: `debug.print " f->"f , " z->" z` For all the 8 of them.

Comment: Information B3: http://imgur.com/a/htSYt           Arrival B16: http://imgur.com/a/6TmG8           Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: And what happens when you do the new `debug.print`? Btw, remove the screenshots, the data is probably something that should stay secure.

Comment: New debug request: http://imgur.com/a/PMaZo        Is the screencap correct? I've ran it, doesn't display anything different.

Comment: put the debug.print line exactly before the yellow line and run again.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/6xcxk         I've removed the images, thanks for the reminder. Here's the updated debug

Comment: Write these in the lines after the debug.print. `debug.print worksheets("Arrival").cells(f,14).value` 
`debug.print worksheets("Information").cells(z,4).value`
On two separate lines.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Ce1he     Doesn't display anything new, neither does this one; http://imgur.com/a/A6uxt

Comment: That is strange. It did not print any values for those two cells. Just to check - `Information` and `Arrival` are named exactly like this? And you do not have any other sheet opened. And you work with `Option Explicit` on top?

Comment: Yes the sheets are called exactly Information and Arrival:http://imgur.com/a/FhJRb                   There are no other sheets opened at the moment.      the Option explicit thing you mentioned doesn't sound familiar to me, what is it?                   Thanks again!

Comment: That's for the option explicit - http://wellsr.com/vba/excel/vba-option-explicit/ probably the problem is somewhere else, but just to make sure. Furthermore, make sure that the cells on those two sheets are not merged and not protected.

Comment: Alright, I've checked the variable box in the option explicit menu. The cells aren't merged. I used 'saved as' on the original file (which had protection) to create my own excel file. I do not think it's protected since I can still enable protection and set a password myself, and it's not required when opening the file.                                      Also, the other monthly files didn't all have this problem.

Comment: Looks strange. I cannot think of another reason.

Comment: I am still thinking. Are you sure that there is no space after "Arrival" in the name of the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put

```
Debug.Print f, z, x
```

before the problematic statement, to monitor the values you are referencing in the worksheet.

The number of rows and columns in a worksheet are limited to:

- 1,048,576 rows
- 16,384 columns

I suspect that the value of `x` has reached too high for the number of columns in the statement

> `If Worksheets("Arrival").Cells(f, 15).Value = Worksheets("Information").Cells(z, x).Value Then`

hence the *Subscript out of range*. But it might be as well any of the other numbers (f or z) referencing rows.

`Debug.Print` these values before the statement should make things clear.

p.s.: you'd also declare all you variables a long to avoid further problems.

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long , z as Long, ....
```